# echoing htmlspecialchars - double encoding?

Tags: php, echo, htmlspecialchars

Using a standard xampp install, and running the following code inside my index.php page, I am receiving what I believe to be odd output.  I'm not certain if it is a bug or if I am just not understanding this correctly.

Having read over numerous threads created here on stack overflow regarding this, I am still not sure why I am receiving this output.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("&"); ?>
```

Will output the following in the source: `&amp;amp;`

But... if I use:

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars("&");
    echo "<br />"
    echo htmlspecialchars("&");
?>
```

The following will be output to source: `&amp;<br />&amp;amp;`

I suppose I am just confused as to why the output, when viewing the html source generated by php, is generated differently when the same statement is used a second time.  I assume it has something to do with double_encoding but have tried several statements to disable and enable double encoding within the htmlspecialchars function but it always seems to output `&amp;amp;` to the last call to htmlspecialchars.

Any additional input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: echo htmlspecialchars("&"); produces a single '&amp;'

Comment: perhaps it is the setup of my php install then?  When using: `echo htmlspecialchars("&");`  the source output always returns `&amp;amp;` on the last echo of that statement.

Comment: I think the extra one is coming from somewhere else. What happens if you do `echo `htmlspecialchars("&") . 'done';`?

Comment: If I concatenate anything onto the statement, the output is indeed corrected.

Comment: Based on your example above, it's something after your lines that is adding it.

Comment: The only code inside my php file is the starting and ending php tag delimiter surrounding the above statement(s).